# "Sue told Johnsy not to move and (to) promise her..."

Tags: to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

Sue said, "Johnsy, don't move and promise me not to look out of the window."

> 1. Sue told Johnsy not to move and **to** promise her not to look out of the window.
>      (OR)
> 2. Sue told Johnsy not to move and promise her not to look out of the window.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: I read sentence 1 as Johnsy has a choice if he wants to promise Sue. In sentence 2, Johnsy has to promise her regardless if he agrees or not.

Comment: Normally, to get the second meaning, you would say, “not to move **or** promise me ....” One exception: the idiom “not to go and” do something means the same thing as not to do something.

Answer (score 0):

1) is correct. She told him **not to do** one thing, **and to promise** her something. The positive **to promise** cancels the negative **not**.

In 2) the sense of 'not' carries on through the sentence. It has not been cancelled, so it is not clear whether he should or shouldn't promise her anything.